# How to add an ArcProgress (lib) to the TitleBar in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I want to create a fade away effect as described in the [Toolbar API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html).

But instead of a static picture, I want to have an `ArcProgress` (From the [Cn1Lib "CircleProgress"](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/CN1CircleProgress)).

Not only that, But the `ArcProgress` should fade away into a `Slider` having the same filling percentage as the AP.

It should "fade into each other" when scrolling down the Form.

Is is possible to do that? if yes, how? I have been working on this quite a long time, please provide a code sample.

**EDIT**

[image: Scrolling down]

On the right you see the screen before scrolling down.

On the left, there should be a slider in the toolbar (I do not know why it is not displayed).

On scrolling down, the circleprogress (right) should fade into a slider (left)

The code for the right

```
ap = new ArcProgress ();
ap.setUnselectedStyle(new Style(0xCCCCCCCC ,0xff0000 , Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_MONOSPACE, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_MEDIUM), (byte) 0b0));
ap.setProgress(10);

myForm.setTitleComponent  (ap); //works
```

The code for the left:

```
Slider jSlider = new Slider();
jSlider.setMaxValue(255);
jSlider.setMinValue(0);
jSlider.setProgress(50); 
jSlider.setEditable(true);
jSlider.setVisible(true);
jSlider.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff0000);
jSlider.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xCCCCCCCC);
jSlider.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0b0);

myForm.setTitleComponent (jSlider); //does not work, for whatever reason
```

Now the main question was:

**How can I make the circleprogress disappear on scrolling down and make the Slider appear on scrolling down?** Secondly: Why is the slider not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem with the toolbar API as described [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-animation-manager.html).
Notice that there is a more complete sample in the `Toolbar` section of [the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html).

You can just place arbitrary components into the toolbar and animate their behavior/functionality based on scroll location.

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());

ArcProgress ap = new ArcProgress ();
ap.setUnselectedStyle(new Style(0xCCCCCCCC ,0xff0000 , Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_MONOSPACE, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_MEDIUM), (byte) 0b0));
ap.setProgress(10);
Slider sl = new Slider();
sl.setProgress(10);
sl.getAllStyles().setOpacity(0);
sl.getSliderEmptyUnselectedStyle().setOpacity(0);
sl.getSliderFullUnselectedStyle().setOpacity(0);
sl.getSliderEmptySelectedStyle().setOpacity(0);
sl.getSliderFullSelectedStyle().setOpacity(0);
sl.getSliderEmptyUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
sl.getSliderFullUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
sl.getSliderEmptySelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
sl.getSliderFullSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

hi.getToolbar().setTitleComponent  (LayeredLayout.encloseIn(sl, ap));

int slHeight = sl.getPreferredH();
int apHeight = ap.getPreferredH();
Motion height = Motion.createLinearMotion(apHeight, slHeight, 100);
Motion opacity = Motion.createLinearMotion(0, 255, 100);

ComponentAnimation cna = new ComponentAnimation() {

    @Override
    public boolean isInProgress() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateState() {
        int s = getStep();
        height.setCurrentMotionTime(s);
        opacity.setCurrentMotionTime(s);
        int h = height.getValue();
        sl.setPreferredH(h);
        ap.setPreferredH(h);
        int o = opacity.getValue();
        sl.getSliderEmptyUnselectedStyle().setOpacity(o);
        sl.getSliderFullUnselectedStyle().setOpacity(o);
        sl.getSliderEmptySelectedStyle().setOpacity(o);
        sl.getSliderFullSelectedStyle().setOpacity(o);
        sl.getSliderEmptyUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(o);
        sl.getSliderFullUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(o);
        sl.getSliderEmptySelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(o);
        sl.getSliderFullSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(o);
        sl.getAllStyles().setOpacity(o);
        ap.getAllStyles().setOpacity(255 - o);
    }
};

hi.getAnimationManager().onTitleScrollAnimation(cna);

for(int iter = 0 ; iter < 50 ; iter++) {
    hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi World"));
}
hi.show();
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I will try this, thanks.

Unfortunately I did not find the first link you send me. It is very hard to find some of the great posts that you do / did on your homepage....

Comment: okay, so I added the ArcProgress to the toolbar, but how can the 'fade-into-slider' animation be done?

Comment: I have been working on this all day, but I cant figure this out... I would need a `MorphTransition` within a single form so i can transform the ArcProgress to a slider. But this is not possible

Comment: Morph transition is for a form not something like that. I suggest spending 30 minutes in writing a small test case with what you would expect to work and a couple of screenshots of what you are trying to achieve visually.

Comment: BTW notice that the slider opacity code is a bit verbose because of the oddities of that component...

Comment: huch, 'easy'... I am in my first year after university, for me this is somehow 'dark magic'... Can you suggest me a tutorial/book/anything on how I can get better in such UI things?

It works now btw, thanks

Comment: If it works you need to accept the answer... I should have added a smilly after the easy as it's not difficult but not intuitive. I've been programming professionally for over 20 years and writing software since early childhood, I have no idea how "normal" people learn stuff but for me it's all easy. Probably the best tip I can give is: find a mentor and ape him. After a few years of that the mentality rubs off and you understand the way he thinks. Make him explain his logic when he pulls something out of the cuff of his sleeve and if he can't explain properly find a better mentor.